# Xamarin iOS Transparent Navigation bar

Tags: xamarin.ios, navbar, transparent

Need to have transparent navigation bar

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/navigation_controller/change_the_nav_bar_transparency/

tried with this but not working.

Any Suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single navigation bar is used for a particular navigation controller in iOS. So if you want to make it transparent for a single VC then you have to make it transparent when you navigate to that VC. And then change it back when you coming back from that VC in viewWillDisappear (or viewDidDisappear) methods.

Answer (score 5):

Although, your question is not fully descriptive and not sure what exactly you want to achieve by saying "Not Working" from the given link.

Write following code in respective override methods of the `ViewController` in which you want to achieve the Transperent `NavigationBar` for that specific `ViewController` only.

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    if (NavigationController != null)
    {
        NavigationController.NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
        NavigationController.NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
        NavigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = true;
        NavigationController.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        NavigationController.NavigationBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
    }
}

public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
    if (NavigationController != null)
    {
        NavigationController.NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(null, UIBarMetrics.Default);
        NavigationController.NavigationBar.ShadowImage = null;
        NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Red; //Provide your specific color here
    }
}
```

If you want to set this Globally, Try it in `AppDelegate`'s `FinishedLaunching` method :

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
UINavigationBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
UINavigationBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
UINavigationBar.Appearance.Translucent = true;
```

Hope this helps!.

Comment: Thanks @MilanG,
Well I wanted to have the navbar transparent on particular ViewController.
Your code did work but it is also affecting other ViewControllers as well.

Comment: I updated my answer to make ViewController specific Transperent Navigationbar.